# 3 jQuery Applications Together - Problem With IE6

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slideshow, fancybox, zooming

I've combined 3 jQuery applications - sortable tabs from jQueryUI, slideshow from Six Revisions, and John Nunemaker's FancyZoom. It can be [seen here](http://www.2webvideo.com/video-production/top-slideshow/tabs-with-slideshow.html).

The combined application works well in FF, Chrome, and Safari, but in IE6 the slideshow does not work properly. The slides overlap the left control button making it non-functional.

Help please!

Partha Bhattacharya

Comment: Stop supporting IE6 - for all our sakes.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a bug in the Six Revisions code. Consider using another one and seeing if the problem still persists. I'd personally love to have the excuse to [use this one](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/), although there's a large list over at [jQuery Plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/slideshow)

If you have any more questions, just comment here and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Thanks Gausie. The Cycle plugin you suggest seems to work with images though they do mention it works with other elements. I though prefer the control arrows keeping in mind that it is important to make the things easy for viewers to see the other slides.

I'm yet to check out the other jQuery plugins, but I'll be grateful if you know of slideshows that have control arrows.

Thanks again.

Comment: Well I haven't looked through all of them, but this looks promising http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/

Comment: Well, seems I could rectify the problem. To overcome the overlapping in IE I centered the slide container in the stylesheet. You can see it working in my <a href="http://www.2webvideo.com/video-production/">blog front page</a>.